# Sitecore Courier set up issues

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to configure a local instance of Sitecore Courier tool in order to compare and get the differences between master and web databases. From the online tutorial it's seems pretty easy to configure but when I'm trying to run the WebRunner project from solution (https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier) I'm getting some weird errors in the console.

Also did the extra configs from here: https://libraries.io/github/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier

[image]

Is there someone who can help please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Sitecore Courier uses C# 6 language features. That is why you are getting build errors. And Editbin.exe could not patch executable that does not exist. Try to install latest C# compiler via Nuget to fix this problem:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

or update you Visual Studio to 2015+ version.